# .htaccess domain open from subfolder then rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, web

I'm trying to make the domain `getvene.com` open in the subfolder `main`. This works fine. But then I need `getvene.com/s/blabla` to be seen as `/?secret-code=blabla`. The RewriteRule can be seen at the bottom. Separately, these rules work fine. But together, the secret code rule has no effect. What needs to be changed?

```
RewriteEngine on

# --- BEGIN domain redirect ---
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+main/
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ http://getvene.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+app/
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ http://app.getvene.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(main|app)/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?getvene\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?app\.getvene\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
# --- END domain redirect ---

# --- BEGIN Secret Code redirect ---
RewriteRule ^s/(.*) /?secret-code=$1 [L]
# --- END Secret Code redirect ---
```

Comment: The rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]` terminates the rewriting pass (`L` flag!), thus the rule below will never get applied.

Comment: Could you provide the full code I need in the answer? If it works I will accept it.

Comment: The short solution for your problem is to change the location of your last rule. Try adding this at the top of other rules but bellow **RewriteEngine on** line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# --- BEGIN domain redirect ---
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+main/
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ http://getvene.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+app/
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ http://app.getvene.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Secret Code redirect
RewriteRule ^s/(.*) /?secret-code=$1

RewriteRule ^(main|app)/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?getvene\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?app\.getvene\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
# --- END domain redirect ---
```